# Jquery mobile unexpected token RBRACE when paste from site in netbeans

Tags: jquery-mobile, netbeans, parsing-error

I'm on jquery mobile demo site and when I copy/paste a part of css in netbeans, it says me (unexpected token rbrace ... parsing error).

I try to copy/paste in notepad before and than copy/paste in netbeans but nothing change.

My encoding is UTF-8 ...

I have the same problem with html (copy/paste).

Have somebody an idea of the problem ?

Comment: You need to provide some samples to reproduce the problem. It could be a bug in NetBeans or it could be a bug in syntax of the copied code

Comment: When you copy and paste from the jQM demo site, unfortunately the spaces are actually &nbsp; characters. If you look in the chrome inspector on your site you will see these characters. Just delete all spaces in the markup copied from the demo site, Or depending on your editor, find the characters and replace them

Comment: @ezanker : ok thanks. So there is no way to avoid it ?